Mean of geometric distribution
I'm trying to prove that $$\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}x(1 - \pi)^{x - 1}\pi = \frac{1}{\pi}.$$
I've seen elsewhere derivations that involve taking the derivative of a slightly modified version of the above sum, but why does changing the index of summation (i.e. $j = x - 1$) not work?

$j=x-1$ makes it $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)(1-\pi)^j$. How do you think you will proceed from here?

What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"?

If you mean the sum is divergent then you are right. "It doesn't exist", would be a good answer. (You can of course say that in some sense the summation can be defined, but such a special request should be made explicit...)

A very odd sum. It diverges! How could it be equal to one over pi ?

@ultralegend5385 sorry, I think I've got it. Using $j = x - 1$ gives $$\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}(j + 1)(1 - \pi)^j\pi,$$ i.e. $$\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}j(1 - \pi)^j\pi + \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}(1 - \pi)^j\pi,$$ i.e. $$\frac{1 - \pi}{\pi} + 1 = \frac{1}{\pi}.$$ Correct?

Nonsense in, nonsense out. The sum diverges.

@Paul but this the expected value of (one version of) the geometric distribution, which is indeed $\mathbb{E}(X) = 1/\pi$. How come it's divergent?

For some probability distributions it could happen that some momenta do not exist.

E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution.

But I guess this is not the case? Here the absolute value common ratio $(1 - \pi)$ is less than 1, as $0 < \pi < 1$. So shouldn't the sum converge?

$$S_n=\sum_{x = 1}^{n}x(1 - \pi)^{x - 1}\pi = \frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{(1-\pi )^n \,\,(\pi  n+1)}{\pi }$$
Let
$$a_n=\frac{(1-\pi )^n \,\,(\pi  n+1)}{\pi }\implies $$ $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-(\pi-1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\pi  n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)   \right)$$
How do you want to have a convergence ?
